# frontend, как правильно дебажить?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, отладка

Как дебажить / собирать метрики и искать баги на фронте, не пытаясь повторить баг у себя локально и заставлять клиента прислать скриншот консоли? Например приложение на react.

Comment: Дополните деталями. Какой фронт, что дебажить какой желаемый результат.

Comment: В мире фронтом называют UI. А он в свою очередь очень различный

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите функцию/форму которая будет отправлять вам то что вы хотите. По типу отправить отчет разрабам или нет.